# Counting number of field and limiting to 10

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code which uses `this` to allow to keep the same function code but apply it to different form elements which can be seen on [a jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/9sX6X/67/)

```
//latest
var maxFields = 10,
    currentFields = 1;

$('.form').on('click', '.add', function () {
      var value_src = $(this).prev();
       var container = $(this).parent().prev();
    if ($.trim(value_src.val()) != '') {
        if (currentFields < maxFields) {
            var value = value_src.val();
            var html = '<div class="line">' +
                '<input id="accepted" type="text" value="' + value + '" />' +
                '<input type="button" value="X" class="remove" />' +
                '</div>';

            $(html).appendTo(container);
            value_src.val('');
            currentFields++;
        } else {
            alert("You tried to add a field when there are already " + maxFields);
        }
    } else {
        alert("You didn't enter anything");
    }

})
    .on('click', '.remove', function () {
       $(this).parents('.line').remove();
    currentFields--;
});
```

My issue is that I still want to be able to limit each section to only have 10 `<inputs>`, but at the moment each section shares the counter, so 5 in requirements and 5 in qualifications would trigger the 10 limit.

Is there a nice clean way of keeping the input field counter separate for each section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is store the current number of children for each list in a context sensitive way. There are a couple ways you could structure this (it would be easy using MVC libraries or the likes), but the simplest solution for your code will be to just use the DOM. So instead of using your global `currentFields` variable, instead use `container.children().length` to get the number of notes in the list you are currently operating on.

http://jsfiddle.net/9sX6X/70/

```
//latest
var maxFields = 10;

$('.form').on('click', '.add', function () {
      var value_src = $(this).prev();
       var container = $(this).parent().prev();
    if ($.trim(value_src.val()) != '') {
        if (container.children().length < maxFields) {
            var value = value_src.val();
            var html = '<div class="line">' +
                '<input id="accepted" type="text" value="' + value + '" />' +
                '<input type="button" value="X" class="remove" />' +
                '</div>';

            $(html).appendTo(container);
            value_src.val('');
        } else {
            alert("You tried to add a field when there are already " + maxFields);
        }
    } else {
        alert("You didn't enter anything");
    }

})
    .on('click', '.remove', function () {
       $(this).parents('.line').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `placeholder` property to identify which button triggered the function.

```
value_src.attr('placeholder');
```

This string can then be used to access three different counters in an associative array.

### Code

```
var maxFields = 10;
var currentFields = new Object;

$('.form').on('click', '.add', function () {
      var value_src = $(this).prev();
      var container = $(this).parent().prev();
    if ($.trim(value_src.val()) != '') {
       var identity =      value_src.attr('placeholder');       

        if(currentFields[identity] == undefined)
        currentFields[identity] = 0;

        if (currentFields[identity] < maxFields)                          {
            var value = value_src.val();
            var html = '<div class="line">' +
                '<input id="accepted" type="text" value="' + value + '" />' +
                '<input type="button" value="X" class="remove" />' +
                '</div>';

            $(html).appendTo(container);
            value_src.val('');
            currentFields[identity]++;
        } else {
            alert("You tried to add a field when there are already " + maxFields);
        } 
    } else {
        alert("You didn't enter anything");
    }

})
    .on('click', '.remove', function () {
       $(this).parents('.line').remove();
    currentFields--;
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9sX6X/73/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to each row like `form-row`

```
var html = '<div class="line form-row">' +
            '<input id="accepted" type="text" value="' + value + '" />' +
            '<input type="button" value="X" class="remove" />' +
            '</div>';
```

and count the length by using

```
console.log($(container).find('.form-row').length);
// Use +1 because initially it is 0
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/9sX6X/69/